# JQuery Form Validator plugin not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make my jQuery form validator work. I spent already 5 hours making it work, researching and stuff, but until now I can't.

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formID").validationEngine();
        });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerBar" ><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The Book of Joy!</h1></div>
    <div id="content" align="center">
    <div id="contentText" align="center">Be a part of our team of IT experts. Apply now!</div>
        <div id="leftContent" align=center></div>
        <div id="rightContent" align=left>
        <b>Signup now!</b>
        <hr>

            <form  id="formID" method = "post" action = "AddApplicantServlet"> 
                <fieldset>
                    <legend id="legendid">Applicant Registration Form</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>First Name:               </td><td><input type = "text" name = fName class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]">           </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Middle Name:              </td><td><input type = "text" name = mName class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]">           </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Last Name:                </td><td><input type = "text" name = lName class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]">           </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Age:                      </td><td><input type = "text" name = age   class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]],maxSize[2]">  </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Gender:                   </td><td><select name = gender><option value='m'>Male</option><option value='f'>Female</option> </select>  </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Email Address:            </td><td><input type = "text" name = email class="validate[required,custom[email]]">        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Contact No:               </td><td><input type = "text" name = contactNumber class="validate[required]"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>City of Residence:        </td><td><input type = "text" name = city   class="validate[required]">         </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>School:                   </td><td><input type = "text" name = school class="validate[required]">       </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Course:                   </td><td><input type = "text" name = course class="validate[required]">       </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Year Graduated:           </td><td><input type = "text" name = yearGraduated class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]],maxSize[4]"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Previous Work Experience: </td><td><input type = "text" name = yearWorkExp class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]],maxSize[2]">  </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Sourcing Channel:         </td><td><select name = sourceChannel> 
                            <option value='Jobstreet'>Jobstreet</option>
                            <option value='Direct'>Direct</option>
                            <option value='Referral'>Referral</option>
                            <option value='Board Exam'>Board Exam</option>
                            <option value='Oath Taking'>Oath  Taking</option>
                            <option value='GradList'>GradList</option> 
                         </select></td></tr>
                            <tr><td> <input type = "submit" value = SUBMIT></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Why is it not working and how can I solve it?

EDIT: I used chromebug and it cannot find my js...  Did I put it on the correct path?

Here are my files:

[image]

This is my chromebug and i don't know what it means.. :(:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to import the plugin's `.js` files. As per the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#readme) you should be adding the following lines as well:

```
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

(and make sure that those files are made available by your webapp as well, i.e. they don't return 404)

Comment: What exactly fails? Is the script loaded? Is the `validationEngine()` function found? Use Firebug to exclude the one and other.

Comment: an error appears.. Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'validationEngine'. what does it mean?

Comment: Then it means that the script is not properly loaded. Check the *Net* tab to be sure. Is the URL in `src` attribute correct? (note: it's relative to the current request URL as you see in browser address bar). Do you see the script when you open it by entering its absolute URL in browser address bar? Does it work if you use an absolute URL in `src` attribute? Etc.

Comment: Newbie use firebug to tell you if the scripts are loaded or not.

Comment: If already installed, open Firebug by F12. Click the *Net* tab. Refresh the page. You should see the `jquery.validationEngine.js` being loaded. What is the HTTP response status? Is it 200 or is it 404 or something else? If 200, then it means that it's OK. If 404, then it means that the URL is wrong or you didn't put the script file at the right place.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /Web_Final_Project/js/index.jsp

Comment: Why did you change the script URL to be `index.jsp`? You should load the validation engine plugin not some JSP file. A JSP file is not a JavaScript file. There's a documentation link in my answer. Click it once again and carefully read the "Usage" section.

Comment: Where should i put it? See the above image for my path... I put it inside WebContent --> js -->

Comment: Yes, put the script there. But you should not change the filename to `index.jsp` or something. It should be `jquery.validationEngine.js`. You should have placed this file in the `js` folder. See also the documentation.

Comment: @BalusC  I add a filter to all pages... does it include javascript?

Comment: Depends on the URL pattern. If it's for example `/*`, then it definitely matches **all** requests.

Comment: i disabled the filter and now the jquery file can be read. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Apparently the filter was been overzealous. Fix the filter's code or URL pattern accordingly. If you want to match only JSP files, then you should use an URL pattern of `*.jsp`. Or if they are all in a certain folder, use `/foldername/*` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's a couple months late but seems like the error happens because jQuery 1.6+ is required for the Validation Engine. It's stated under the **Rules of Thumb** section on https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine. "From 2.2.4 and up, jquery 1.6+ is required because of prop()". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit that you have is that javascript(jquery) does not know anything about JSP/ASP/PHP or any other server side technology.  So you can take the outputted html and troubleshoot it starting there.

At a glance, I do not see the javascript validation plugin being added.  Is it now part of the core?

Comment: Actually, there is no single line of server side code in the HTML.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was pointing out that this problem that they have would exist outside of the technology used.  I get a lot of questions about why javascript is not working in a particular server-side technology. Well the fact is that it is not the server side, but rather the pure outputted html where the problem always exists.